# Auto loading resources in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Is there a way to autoload resources in CakePHP?
Like autoload.php config file in CodeIgniter...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Short question with not a lot detail so you'll get a short answer:

Check the App class, check bootstrap.php. App is thought for loading additional resources and bootstrap, well, the name says it.